# Ubuntu does not recognize external monitors when attached through docking station

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-monitor, displaylink, docking

I just bought a Lenovo USB 3.0 Docking Station.
It works with my keyboard, but not with the monitors: ubuntu just does no recognize the external monitors when I connect them.

Sorry for the lack of details, I am a newbie and I really do not know where to look for. It would be really good if anyone can help me with that.

thanks

EDIT:

Computer: Lenovo Thinkpad T480s
Ubuntu: 18.04
Docking station: Thinkpad USB 3.0 Ultra: https://www.lenovo.com/de/de/accessories-and-monitors/docking/universal-cable-docks-usb/ThinkPad-USB-3-0-Ultra-Dock/p/40A80045EU

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include  the Ubuntu version, computer model and docking station model.

Comment: USB 3.0 docking stations in most cases use DisplayLink hardware for video output. You can find the necessary drivers and installation instructions [here](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu).

Comment: @danzel I updates wiht this info (sorry for forgetting!) I will update the driver.

Comment: @danzel It worked! Thanks a lot, you do not know how happy you made me :)
If you convert your comment to an answer, I can accept it for the future.

Comment: @danzel I had tried many other things. Out of disappointment your solution worked for me. I wish you had this as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: For me installing the drivers didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Posting as posted by "danzel" in comments above. All credit to the guy. Hence posting this as a guest:
"USB 3.0 docking stations in most cases use DisplayLink hardware for video output. You can find the necessary drivers and installation instructions [here](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu). "

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  This answer is an extension of discussion in comments and is incomplete as an answer.  Link-only answers are considered low-quality because they become obsolete if the link is changed, moved, or deleted.  We also can't keep link-only answers up-to-date via moderation.  Nobody should actually have to visit any link to understand an answer:  all of the essential parts of the answer should be posted here.    I suggest that you make an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1265365/edit) to make this answer complete.

Comment: Installing the package from the link doesn't solve anything.

Comment: I'm confirming that installing this driver has solved my problem

Comment: this did not work for me: ASUS TUF Gaming A17, the second screen via docking station works on Windows